# Cohomology Finite covering and Weyl group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $G$ a compact Lie group, $T$ a maximal torus in $G$ and $W=N(T)/T$ its Weyl group. Then we have a finite covering (why is a covering?)
$ W \rightarrow G/T \rightarrow G/N(T) $
Has $G/N(T)$ a manifold structure? 
How can I prove (rigorously) that there is an isomorphism
$ H^{*}(G/T)^{W} \simeq H^{*}(G/N(T)) $?
where $H^{*}(G/T)^{W}$ denotes the $W$-invariant elements of $H^{*}(G/T)$

Comment: can you just prove everything by writing out the details? it should not that hard.

Comment: I think that concern with invariant forms...

Comment: cohomology is just a disguise; this also holds for representation rings in general. Can you make a functor rhetoric proof?

Comment: No... but I am intrested on it